# How to input data for constructor that is passed in as a pointer for Employee Class?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I am trying to pass a string pointer that points to name for my constructor along with two other data types. I don't know how to write my code in a way where I dont have to overload the stream operator so that the data in int main can be read.

I've tried dereferencing, the get method as you see, and I'm lost.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
private:
    string name;
    int emp_ID;
    int emp_GrossSal;
    double emp_Savings;

public:
    Employee()
    {
        string name = "";

    }

    Employee(string *n,int , int )
    {
        name = *n;
        emp_ID = NULL;
        emp_GrossSal = NULL;
        //emp_Savings = (.1*emp_GrossSal);
    }
    //get and set methods
    int getSalary();
    double getSavings();
    int getEmp_ID();
    string getName() const;

    void setEmp_ID(int);
    void setSalary(int);
    void setName(const string &);

    //functions
    void displayEmp();
    ~Employee();

    //overloaded operators
    void operator =(const Employee &right)
    {
            name = right.name;
            emp_GrossSal = right.emp_GrossSal;
            emp_ID = right.emp_ID;
            emp_Savings = right.emp_Savings;

    }

};
int Employee::getEmp_ID()
{
    return emp_ID;
}
int Employee::getSalary()
{
    return emp_GrossSal;
}
double Employee::getSavings()
{

    return (emp_GrossSal*(1/100));
}
string Employee::getName() const
{
    return name;
}
void Employee::setEmp_ID(int t)
{
    emp_ID = t;
}
void Employee::setSalary(int s)
{
    emp_GrossSal = s;
}
void Employee::setName( const string &n)
{
    name = n;
}

void Employee::displayEmp()
{

    cout << "Employee Name:" << name << endl;
    cout << "Employee ID  :" << emp_ID << endl;
    cout << "Employee Gross Salary: " << emp_GrossSal << endl;
    cout << "Employee Savings: " << emp_Savings << endl;
    cout << "Employee Monthy Salary: $ " << emp_GrossSal / 12 << endl;



}
Employee::~Employee()
{
}
int main()
{
    Employee One;
    string inputName;
    int ID, Gross_Sal, choice;

    cout << "Enter the number of Employees: " << endl;
    cin >> choice;


    cout << "\t\tPlease enter the Employee's Information Below\n\n" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the employees Name: " << endl;
    cin >> inputName;
    One.setName(inputName);
    cout << "Enter the employees ID:     " << endl;
    cin >> ID;
    One.setEmp_ID(ID);
    cout << "Employee Gross Salary:        " << endl;
    cin >> Gross_Sal;
    One.setSalary(Gross_Sal);


    One.displayEmp();

    system("Pause");
    return 0;

}
```

I'm trying to output the Employees information like name, etc. Just trying to manage the name part first.

Comment: [if getName return a string& then you could do `cin >> One.getName();`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bbe0b15fdf7d9a6) but as is you're trying to read into function pointer...

Comment: Would it be acceptable to pass by reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If you're trying to set the employee's name, set the name to n, not the other way around.

    Employee(string *n,int , int )
    {
        *n = name; (This should be name = *n;) I believe.
        emp_ID = NULL;
        emp_GrossSal = NULL;
        //emp_Savings = (.1*emp_GrossSal);
    }
```

As for setting the employee name, I would make a setter function, but as is, you can also make the getter return a reference instead, and this should then work:

```
 Employee One;
    char name;
    cout << "\t\tPlease enter the Employee's Information Below\n\n" << 
        endl;
    cout << "Enter the employees Name: ";
    cin >> One.getName();  (*(One.getName()) if using pointer)

    One.displayEmp();
```

Edit:

```
void Employee::setName(const string& name_)
{
    name = name_;
}


Employee One;
char name;
cout << "\t\tPlease enter the Employee's Information Below\n\n" << endl;
cout << "Enter the employees Name: ";
string inputName;
cin >> inputName;
One.setName(inputName);

One.displayEmp();
```

Edit#2:

```
//NOTE: Your issue here is the way your set salary and display functions work
    class Employee
    {
    private:
        string name;
        int emp_ID;
        int emp_GrossSal;
        //NOTE: This is never set
        double emp_Savings;

    public:

    double Employee::getSavings()
    {
        //NOTE: This is never called
        return (emp_GrossSal*(1/100));
    }
    void Employee::setSalary(int s)
    {
        //NOTE: Only the emp_GrossSal is set, emp_savings isn't
        emp_GrossSal = s;
    }
    void Employee::displayEmp()
    {
        cout << "Employee Gross Salary: " << emp_GrossSal << endl;
        //NOTE: When you print out savings, you use emp_Saving which was never set.
        cout << "Employee Savings: " << emp_Savings << endl;
    }
```

You've got two solutions to this, either you need to set the savings as shown below:

```
void Employee::setSalary(int s)
{
    emp_GrossSal = s;
    emp_Savings = (s * 0.1);
}
```

Or you can get rid of the emp_Savings variable entirely since it isn't being used anywhere, and just call your get savings function instead of using the member variable as shown below:

```
void Employee::displayEmp()
{
    cout << "Employee Gross Salary: " << emp_GrossSal << endl;
    //NOTE: This function will actually just get the salary divided by 10
    //NOTE: You want to keep this a function in case you change percentage in the future
    cout << "Employee Savings: " << getSavings() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response I tried using On.getName() and I still get the same error binary operator not found. I added a setter method and changed the constructor. any other suggestions?

Comment: Yea, I recommend using an intermediary variable. Added code sample before, let me know if that doesn't work!

Comment: thank you for help really appreciate it. You think you might be able to help with my function returning a weird number?it returns a long decimal number instead of 10% of gross salary.                        
 double Employee::getSavings()
{
 
 return (emp_GrossSal*(1/100));
}

Comment: Sure thing :)  Just to clarify, you want it to return 10% of the gross salary? Not the emp_Savings? Can you give me an example of the output you're currently getting vs what kind of output you want?

Comment: I get Enter the number of Employees:
1
                Please enter the Employee's Information Below


Enter the employees Name:
name
Enter the employees ID:
1
Employee Gross Salary:
100
Employee Name:name
Employee ID  :1
Employee Gross Salary: 100
Employee Savings: -9.25596e+61
Employee Monthy Salary: $ 8
Press any key to continue . . .                                                                                           It should return the savings contribution which is calculated as %10 of grossSalary

Comment: In the code you've posted above, you haven't set the employee Salary at any point, could you update the code?

Comment: yea I set it.            void Employee::setSalary(int s)
{
 emp_GrossSal = s;
}    I went back and edited it after a few exchanges with you and It still produced -9.2...

Comment: I'm asking if you can edit your original post with the updated code, so I can have a better idea as to the problem :)

Comment: sorry, I went ahead and updated the original code. Let me know what you think or find whats wrong here.. :)

Comment: There we go, added a couple code fixes above in edit 2, that should fix it! Let me know if there's any other problem :D! And please consider accepting my answer (it's good for my brittle ego)